# sails-hook-cron In the config/cron.js file, schedule:'* * * * * *' could be a variable?

Tags: javascript, cron, sails.js

I'm working with sailsJS and sails-hook-cron.

I want to set the "schedule" var of the config/cron.js file with a variable that comes from a MySQL query to the DB.

is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, well, not if you want to start Cron jobs dynamically anyway, which is probably the only reason why you would be looking to start a job with info from a db.

Instead you can use a Service. A very basic example would be to create a file called CronService.js in the api/services folder.

```
// CronService.js
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
module.exports = {
    startJob : function(time) {
        new CronJob(time, function() {
          // does whatever you need to do.
        }, null, true);
    }
}
```

This service can then be called in a controller. Eg.

```
startCronService : function(req, res, next) {
    // Call mysql db and get the schedule data.
    // Set the time variable with the schedule data and start the job
    var time = '10 * * * * *';
    CronService.startJob(time);
    res.ok();
},
```

For full details on using the cron package, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron